# Is my proof that $\log_23$ is transcendental correct?

Tags: proof-verification, logarithms, transcendental-numbers

Could anyone please check my following proof that $\log_23$ is transcendental?
If it is not correct, could you note how to prove that $\log_23$ is transcendental in another way?

Theorem: $\log_23$ is transcendental.

Lemma $1$: $\log_23$ is irrational.

Prove the lemma by contradiction:

Suppose $\log_23$ is rational. Then it can be written as a ratio of two positive integers $p, q$: $\log_23 = \frac{p}{q}$ (clearly $\log_23$ is positive).
Then, from the definition of logarithms, $2^{(p/q)}=3$. Now, if we raise both sides of the equation to the power of $q$, we get $2^p = 3^q$. But $2$ to the power of any positive integer is an even number and $3$ to the power of any positive integer is an odd number, so $2^p = 3^q$ has no solution for positive integers $p, q$ (contradiction). So $\log_23$ cannot be rational, it must be irrational. This proves the lemma.

We will now prove the theorem that $\log_23$ is transcendental by contradiction.
Suppose $\log_23$ is algebraic. We already proved it is irrational, so we suppose it is algebraic irrational.
Then, via Gelfond-Schneider we know that if $a$ is a positive integer larger than $1$ and $b$ is algebraic irrational, then $a^b$ is transcendental.
So if $\log_23$ is algebraic irrational, then any positive integer larger than $1$ raised to the power of $\log_23$ is transcendental. But from the definition of logarithms, $2^{\log_23} = 3$ which obviously isn't transcendental (contradiction). So $\log_23$ cannot be algebraic, it must be transcendental.

Comment: What does the $3$ mean? Do you just mean $\log(2)\cdot 3$ or $\log(2)^3$ or something else?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: ...or $\log_2(3)$? or the other way around: $\log_3(2)$.... as you can see, curious, you need to "pin down" exactly what you mean by $\log(2)3$.

Comment: Assuming you mean $\log_2(3)$, this is correct (but maybe a bit more verbose than necessary).

Comment: I upvoted your comment, @RobertIsrael, because you acknowledged that the askers proofs were correct.  As far as suggesting that it "may be a bit more verbose than necessary",  students are encouraged to justify every step along the way, in their proofs, and I would prefer my students say more than not saying enough.  Of course there's a middle ground, but that's something one learns through experience.

Answer (score 6):

You've successfully proved the the Lemma, and then the Theorem. And should feel proud that you succeeded.

I post this "community post" in part, so that an answer exists, and is posted objectively, (no one has anything to gain), hence  removing one potential "unanswered" questions.

Comment: In particular, dear @XPenguen,  [There are currently almost 175,000 questions that are left answerless](https://math.stackexchange.com/unanswered)