# Diophantine properties of $\log(3)/\log(2)$ (and other questions)

Tags: continued-fractions, diophantine-approximation

Let's call $\gamma \in \mathbb R$ **$\alpha$-badly approximable** if there is some $d>0$ such that for all pairs $(k,l)\in \mathbb Z^2$ such that $ l\neq 0,$

$$ \left| \gamma - \frac kl \right| > \frac d{|l|^\alpha} .$$

I was simply wondering the following:

**Question 1.** Take for example $\displaystyle \gamma = \frac{\log(3)}{\log(2)}$. Is there any known value of $\alpha$ for which $\gamma$ is $\alpha$-badly approximable?

Furthermore, it is well-known that a number is 2-badly approximable (a.k.a. **Diophantine**) if and only if the sequence of integers corresponding to its continued fraction expansion is bounded.

For example, the golden ratio $\phi = [1;1,1,1,\ldots]$ and $\sqrt 2 = [1;2,2,2,\ldots]$ (or any non-rational algebraic number).

**Question 2.** Can one deduce any properties of the continued fraction expansion if a number is $\alpha$-badly approximable in general, or indeed deduce $\alpha$-badly approximability from the continued fraction expansion?

**Question 3.** Is it at all easy to provide for a given $\alpha > 2$, examples of numbers which are $\alpha$-badly approximable but not Diophantine?

(For any such $\alpha>2$ this is Lebesgue almost-always true by Jarnik's Theorem.)

Comment: [Liouville's Theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_Theorem_(Number_Theory)) states that any algebraic number is badly approximable. $\gamma$ from **question 1** is [transcendental](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2276970/is-my-proof-that-log-23-is-transcendental-correct).

Comment: For the $\gamma$ of your first question perhaps it is informative to see the heuristics of this approximation towards some millions of digits. http://go.helms-net.de/math/collatz/2hochS_3hochN_V2.htm I've made this treatize a couple of years ago and it likely should be polished one time. But perhaps you can take from the impressive pictures/trends/data estimates for your $\alpha$ (or lower/upper limits for it)?