# Independent over rational number field

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, independence, transcendental-numbers

Is there some theorems which can make sure that
$$1, \frac{\log 2}{\log 3}, \frac{\log 3}{\log 2}$$
are $\mathbb{Q}$-independent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\def\Q{\mathbb{Q}}$
**Edit**: Suppose $$1, \frac{\log 2}{\log 3}, \frac{\log 3}{\log 2}$$ are $\Q$-dependent. That means that there exists $a,b,c\in\Q$, not all zero, such that
\begin{equation}
b\cdot1+a\frac{\log 2}{\log 3}+c\frac{\log 3}{\log 2}=0.
\end{equation}
Without loss of generality, we can suppose $a,b,c$ to be integers, and $a>0$. If $a=0$, then we easily get a contradiction. Now, set
$$
x=\frac{\log 2}{\log 3}.
$$
Observe that
$$
x=\log_3 2.
$$
Now we have
$$
b+ax+cx^{-1}=0,
$$
so
$$
ax^2+bx+c=0.
$$
But $x=\log_3 2$ is notoriously trascendental (see [$\log_3 2$ is trascendental](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2276970/is-my-proof-that-log-23-is-transcendental-correct)), contradiction. Therefore $$1, \frac{\log 2}{\log 3}, \frac{\log 3}{\log 2}$$ are $\Q$-independent.

Comment: You use $x<0$, but $x>0$.

Comment: I usually assume $\log x$ to be the inverse function of $e^x$. Perhaps you mean something else?

Comment: $\log 2$, $\log 3$ are both positive.

Comment: $\log$ means logarithm in base $e$.

Comment: Now everything should work fine.

Comment: @AntonioFicarra, does it matter? As long as the base is greater than one, both $\log 2$ and $\log 3$ are positive.

Comment: @AntonioFicarra Thanks!